# Is it possible to receive a post_save signal that comes from a particular modelform's save() instead of simply anytime the instance is saved?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

If a model has w, x, y, z attributes, and a modelform based on this model has fields only for w and x, how can I wire up a post_save_receiver(or similar) for only the modelform?

I'd like the receiver to ignore `save()`s to y and z. And only carry out the code within the post_save function if a particular form or particular field was updated.

The following code should carry out depending on the fields saved, or modelform saved:

```
def profile_post_save_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    ...

post_save.connect(profile_post_save_receiver, sender=Profile)
```

And here are two separate modelforms. The `post_save` code should happen only when `PreferenceUpdateForm` is updated, and ignore changes to `ProfileUpdateForm`:

```
from .models import Profile
from django import forms

class PreferenceUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [
            "preference1",
            "preference2",
        ]

class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [
            "bio",
            "profile_image",
        ]
```

If this isn't the ideal way to go about this, how else can I achieve similar results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signals are not the right way to do this, especially if you're writing the model forms yourself. Just override the form's [`save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) method to do whatever you need to. Something like this:

```
class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Call parent save() method
        instance = super(ProfileUpdateForm, self).save(commit)
        # Now you can do whatever work you need to with the instance
        # that has just been saved.
```